# Accelerated C++ on quotients

Tags: c++, division, accelerated-c++

I am reading the book "Accelerated C++". In the details of chapter 2, a description of division between two numbers and extracting their quotient is provided:

> x / y
>
> Quotient of x and y . If both operands are integers,
>   the implementation chooses whether to round toward zero or - 8

I don't understand this one. What does "round toward [...] - 8" mean? What implementations use that and why?

Well I tried searching for that but didn't find anything.

Comment: I dunno, rounding toward -8 could be awesome.

Comment: @Yakk I think technically rounding toward -8 is a conforming implementation in C++03?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book probably means [round towards negative infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Directed_roundings), i.e. -∞:

Directed roundings

- Round toward 0 – directed rounding towards zero (also known as truncation).
- Round toward +∞ – directed rounding towards positive infinity (also known as rounding up or ceiling).
- Round toward −∞ – directed rounding towards negative infinity (also known as rounding down or floor).

Either there was a typesetting error, or you are not seeing it correctly.